# Magento upload product error

Tags: php, magento, upload

I'm new for Magento. When I upload file in Product details as 'Downloadable Product', It's uploading fully and showing 100%. But when I click, 'Save' it's giving alert as

```
There are files that were selected but not uploaded yet.
Please upload or remove them first.
```

Actually file size 70MB. If I upload small file, here No problem.

Where is mistake?

Answer (score 1):

upload_max_filesize AND post_max_size have to be set to according values. 
configure php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize = 1000M
upload_tmp_dir = /tmp
post_max_size = 1000M
```

Answer (score 0):

try change your .httacess file, add code below

```
#Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 100M
#Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 100M
```